# AngularJS - Return in success $http.post

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I use AngularJs and I need to return a data after a $http.post connection. This is the code:

```
app.controller('PrincipalController',['$http', '$scope', function($http,$scope){
  $scope.myData = 0;
  $http.post("server/checklogin.php",
    {id: "id",email: "email",password: "password"}
  )
  .success(function(data){
    console.log($scope.myData) //0
    $scope.myData = data;
    console.log($scope.myData); // 1
}
```

OLD: How can I pass the data into myData? - Thanks for your answers and sorry if I haven't explained well.

But now, in html, `{{myData}}` what can I write?

I do not know if it's fundamental, but I'll have to use "myData" with an "ng-if"..

EDIT: Thanks! I think that I've solved! :D

Comment: Sorry i cannot understand the question, you just do 'myData = data' inside the 'success' function, what's the problem?

Comment: Whatever you wish to do with data has to be with in success. You cannot take it outside because of the async nature.

Comment: The only angularish way to do what you want, i.e. using asynchronously retrieved data in a synchronous way is to use the $resource service which will fill in your myData variable (provided it is in the $scope) when the data is back from the server. $http does not provide this functionality right away and the only place where you can use the data returned is in the callback.

Comment: either use `this.myData or $scope.myData` not both

Comment: @entre ok.. But it doesn't works.. What do I do?

Answer (score 7):

Typically in your service you will return the promise

```
myService.getCheckLogin = function {
    return $http.post("server/checklogin.php",
      {id: "id",email: "email",password: "password"}
      );
}
```

then in controller

```
myService.getCheckLogin()
.success(function(data){
  $scope.myData = data;
}
.error(function(err){
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't be closing ')' of success method before .error call?

Answer (score 2):

you should do something like this:

```
.success(function(data){
    $scope.myData = data;
    //OR
    myCallback(data);
    console.log(data) //data = 1 (server works);
}
```

You cannot put the assignment right after the post call, because the call is asynchronous, you cannot predict the exact moment when it will be returning.

I used the `$scope`, because normally you might use it through a service on a controller where a scope is available. Otherwise you can use a function in a callback