# AngularJS controller does console.log() before service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am developing an app in M.E.A.N stack. I'm using an angular controller (from a directive), and a service. The controller calls the service, the service sends a GET request to NodeJS and gets a result. Then I log the result in the service and I get the data.

The problem is that the controller also logs the service before the controller gets results.

In services.js:

```
var self = this;
self.show = function() {
    $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    });
```

In directives.js:

```
this.contacts = contactsSrv.show();
console.log(this.contacts);
```

And that's what I see in the console:
[image]

(The directive logs before it gets results from `contactsSrv.show()`)

How can I make the `contactsSrv.show()` asynchronous?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Return in success $http.post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476111/angularjs-return-in-success-http-post)

Answer (score 2):

Using .then as promise return

service.js

```
var self = this;
self.show = function() {
    return $http.get('/contactlist');
};
```

directive.js

```
contactsSrv.show()
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        this.contacts = response;
    });
```

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski sens of answer? I was changing this to work as it was the top voted answer.

Comment: @K.Burrell - to clarify - top voted answer was wrong, was not working in expected way and someone vote for it.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Yes that is correct, I thought it would be easier for clarity to correct the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get` replaced by `$http.jsonp` as I need to retrive some data from ouside stackoverflow.

Replace `success` with `then` method - so you can chain results in controller / run section.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('contactsSrv', function($http) {
    this.show = function() {
      return $http.jsonp('//public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/wtmpeachtest.wordpress.com/posts?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
    }
  }).run(function(contactsSrv) {
    contactsSrv.show().then(function(r) {
      console.log('found posts', r.found)
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
</div>
```